# Para que sirve el siguiente algoritmo

Tags: java

```
public void eliminar(int index){

    if(index==0){

        cabeza=cabeza.obtenerSiguiente();

    }else{

        int contador=0;

        Nodo temporal=cabeza;

        while(contador<index-1){

            temporal=temporal.obtnerSiguiente();

            contador++;
        }

        temporal.enlazarSiguiente(temporal.obtenerSiguiente().obtenerSiguiente());
    }

    size--;
```

Comment: elimina un nodo de una estructura y nuevamente lo enlaza

Answer (score 8):

Elimina el elemento de la posición deseada, de la siguiente manera:
Suponga que [x] es un elemento de la lista encadenada (Nodo).

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente estructura de nodos:

[1]-[2]-[3]-[4]-[5]-[6]
Supongamos que ocurre la siguiente llamada: eliminar(0);

```
public void eliminar(int index)
{
    if(index==0)
    {
        // cabeza = [1]-[2]-[3]-[4]-[5]-[6];
        cabeza=cabeza.obtenerSiguiente();
        // cabeza = [2]-[3]-[4]-[5]-[6];
    }
    else
    ...
    size--;
}
```

Ahora supongamos que la siguiente entrada: eliminar(3);

```
public void eliminar(int index)
{
    ...
    else
    {
        int contador = 0;
        Nodo temporal = cabeza;
        // temporal = [1]-[2]-[3]-[4]-[5]-[6];
        // Cada vuelta: 0 < 3 - 1(TRUE) // 1 < 3 - 1(TRUE) // 2 < 3 - 1(FALSE)
        while(contador<index-1)
        {
            //realización de este codigo 2 tiempos
            temporal=temporal.obtnerSiguiente();
            // temporal en la primera ronda = [2]-[3]-[4]-[5]-[6];
            // temporal en la segunda ronda = [3]-[4]-[5]-[6];
            // cabeza = [1]-[2]-[3]-[4]-[5]-[6]
            contador++;
        }
        // contador = 2;
        // temporal.obtenerSiguiente() = [4]-[5]-[6]
        // temporal.obtenerSiguiente().obtenerSiguiente() = [5]-[6]
        temporal.enlazarSiguiente(temporal.obtenerSiguiente().obtenerSiguiente());
        // temporal.enlazarSiguiente... = [3]-(Eliminado)-[5]-[6]
        // cabeza = [1]-[2]-[3]-[5]-[6]
    }

    size--;
}
```